# php to output facebook group member count

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I have a code that outputs member count of a facebook group. However, it does not show the correct number. 
1.It will always show a less count
2.Sometimes it shows 0
I have installed the sdk and also I am a subscriber of the group where I am running this code so ideally it should permit me and give the correct result. Can someone shed some light on it?

```
<?php
  require_once('src/facebook.php');
  $config = array(
    'appId' => 'MY APP ID',
    'secret' => 'MY SECRET',
    'cookie' => true
  );
  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $query = urlencode("SELECT uid FROM group_member WHERE gid = 000000000000000");
  try {
    $fbData = $facebook->api("/fql?q={$query}");
    $member_count =  count($fbData['data']);
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {};
?>
<div><?php echo $member_count; ?></div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct appID and secret, check gid in mysql "$query"...

Do you have good src to facebook.php and you import lib ?

Comment: Things shown in the post are sample. I have entered a correct appid and secret. gid what I am entering is also correct. and i have uploaded the required sdk files to my hosting space in the src folder

Comment: Please take photo(screen).

Comment: I didnt get what you are trying to convey. Is that a php syntax?

Comment: Take photo, what are you see on website ?

Comment: i dont have a website. i am just checking it in a plain blank .php file which is uploaded to my webspace. Presently it outputs 21 whereas it should output 33 because there are 33 members in the group.

Comment: Write there url to dev website with this (facebook dev).

Comment: I am sorry but I am not understanding you. I have a code that runs perfectly. Its just that it show less count. The group has 33 members and the php echo $member_count shows only 21. I just want to know why it shows LESS COUNT and sometime for other subscribed groups it shows ZERO.

Comment: send me code of this to mail:  szalony.arti@poczta.fm

Comment: Hey, Check email box!